# Event Tracking Not Showing up in Reports

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting up a Javascript timer to grab the time-on-site for one page only with the following event tracking code:

```
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

When I check the Network tab, there are outgoing pings to GA but in GA, there are no reports.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to simply wait a duration of time before the event tracking turns on. Apparently, with GA, the time is quite variable.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics code in a web page usually consists of two parts:

1. Code to load the `ga.js` analytics code from google-analytics.com
2. Code to set the analytics account and specify what to track.

The code you've shown is only the first part which loads `ga.js`. You're missing the code telling Google Analytics what to do/track -- something like

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```